# Laravel delaying emails breaks links

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-blade

I need to send e-mails with a delay of a couple hours. Everything I create in the construct function of my mailable works: image links, pulling stuff from the database, ...

The mails look good but the only weird thing is that all the outgoing links appear to be broken.

In a mail without a delay the link looks like this: https://example.url.com/

In a mail with delay it looks like this: http://localhost/email/n?l=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.url.com&h=Kv1wny2TTU8RhdgPUXQEDpX8xHdKavz1

I have no idea why these links transform to this... I tested it without a delay and everything works like it should.

I use the delay like this:

```
Mail::to($contestant->email)->locale('en')->later(now()->addMinutes(1), new NurtureMail($contestant));
```

The only other thing I use on the emails is this tracker https://github.com/jdavidbakr/mail-tracker for some reporting. I don't know if that has something to do with it..

**Edit 1:**

I generate the links in 2 ways: with stuff from the db, or from translations like this:

```
class NurtureMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $offerLink;
    private $site;

    public function __construct($contestant)
    {
        $this->contestant = $contestant;
        
        $this->brand = $this->contestant->brand; 
        
        ...

        $this->site = 'https://'.$this->brand.'.'.'com';
        $this->offerLink = trans('mail.offerLink.dacia');
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->senderMail, $this->senderName)
                    ->subject($this->mailSubject)
                    ->view('emails.email', [
                        'offerLink' => $this->offerLink,
                        'site' => $this->site,
                    ]);
    }
}
```

In email.blade.php i use the links like this for example:

```
<a href="{{ $offerLink }}">
  Click me
</a>
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are generating the url in your question.

Comment: @KurtFriars just edited it

Comment: Does disabling `mail-tracker` resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APP_URL in my .env file was 'http://localhost' so mail-tracker used that to transform the tracked links.

Once I changed it to the correct url, it worked fine